# What are the differences between Lua For Windows and LuaDist?

Tags: lua

I'm just wondering what the difference is between Lua For Windows and LuaDist.  I have discovered that LuaDist seems to be portable, as in not needing to be installed but can just be extracted and good to go.  Are there any modules that are missing?

Comment: from the landing page of LuaDist: About LuaDist

LuaDist is a true multi-platform package management system that aims to provide both source and binary repository of modules for the Lua programming language.

Answer (score 0):

from the landing page of LuaDist: "LuaDist is a true multi-platform package management system that aims to provide both source and binary repository of modules for the Lua programming language. "

So technically you wil need Lua For Windows OS because that is the base lua installation where you have the executables to run lua code and modules. After you have LuaDist will help you install a specific lua module, like the postgresql database module for example, with all the dependencies resolved for your platform OS and LUA version.

Answer (score 0):

Lua for Windows is a package containing a Lua 5.1 interpreter, various modules (plain Lua and precompiled C modules), documentation, and an editor, all bundled in a nice GUI installer (which also registers file types, etc.). It was meant to get Windows users started who don't want to compile stuff for themselves.

The LuaDist project on the other hand ports the build systems of various C modules and their dependencies(!) to CMake so that they can be built on all supported platforms in a consistent way. It features Lua scripts to select and automatically compile custom subsets of the modules in the repository, but it also includes precompiled binaries in its repository. There is a [predefined collection of modules](https://github.com/LuaDist/batteries) in the LuaDist repository that is modeled after the Lua for Windows distribution.

Neither Lua for Windows nor LuaDist have *all* modules available ([Lua for Windows](https://github.com/rjpcomputing/luaforwindows#libraries-included), [LuaDist](https://github.com/LuaDist/Repository)). At the moment the precompiled binaries of Lua for Windows and LuaDist are incompatible with each other, because they use different C runtime libraries.